# Spring AOP doesn't work on dependencies(Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am trying to implement AOP on my project, which has ***multiple API connector clients*** added as ***pom
dependencies***.  The dependencies cannot be modified so I am trying to add the AOP logic on the parent project.

Example. Project A

```
<dependencies>
    <!------ other dependencies ------->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>x.y</groupId>
       <artifactId>api-client-b</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>p.q</groupId>
       <artifactId>api-client-c</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The AOP code works well when applied to classes of Project A, but when I try to add it to some class inside let say **api-client-b** or **api-client-c** it doesn't work. Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong, also suggest a work around?

**Please Note:** I cannot modify the **api-client-b** and **api-client-c**

Comment: if you can't modify api-client-b and api-client-c, how do you assume to change their behavior?

Comment: You'll have to wrap those B and C client classes.  You can't expect them to know about Spring Boot or your aspects.

Comment: And it should work because? Are those classes registered as beans and used as beans or are they created with `new`? Does your aspect actually match those classes (the pointcut expressions). All in all there is just too little information to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the source code of the aspect or applying AOP on class files or JAR files, then you can do a post-compile time weaving or load-time weaving.

The concept is very well explained in this article

https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to create a bean out of each of the API Clients. As the Clients were not having @Component annotations on them, the Objects of the Clients were not present as managed bean on the Spring container.